# Removing entries from another file

Tags: excel, duplicates, filtering

I have two very large files we'll call Old and New. New contains many entries that Old contains. What I need to do is remove any entry from New that Old contains. There are 9,459 entries in Old with 55 columns. New contains 11,983 entries with 76 columns. I need to make the comparison based on 5 columns; 'name_last', 'name_first', 'name_middle', 'street', and 'type'

I'm using Excel 2010, I'm very new to it, and haven't got a clue where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make up a concatenated column in each file to "glue" together 'name_last', 'name_first', 'name_middle', 'street', and 'type'. Something like
  this
  `=LOWER(A2&B2&C2&D2&E2)`
  (The `LOWER` will let you run a case insensitive search)

[image]

- Add a formula like this (change sheet names and columns to suit)
  `=ISNA(MATCH(F2,[old.xlsx]Sheet2!$F:$F,0))`
  to look up each value in column F of "new.cls" against the entire list of concatenated values in "old.xls"

[image]

- AutoFilter the `TRUE` results to return the non-matches, then delete these rows

[image]

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, this is all over my head. =[
I've discovered the "sheets" thing, so now I have Old and New in the same xlsx file. I've exported both files to tab delimited text file, and then glued the files together manually with Notepad, then imported the text file. Now I have one massive file. Is there some way to only show rows based on double entries?

Comment: @andrewjackson Hi, have you solved it now you have marked this as accepted? You can run the same approach on two separate sheets inside the one file

Comment: I have not solved it. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have my column of unique values in both files, the unique files are on column A. I made a separate column under B so store my boolean. So I use `=ISNA(MATCH(A2,[old.xlsx]Sheet2!$A:$A,0))` which I know is not in old.xlsx, and I get true. Then I do the same for `=ISNA(MATCH(A3,[old.xlsx]Sheet2!$A:$A,0))` which I know is in old.xlsx, and I still get true.

Comment: Okay, I just realized I forgot to change "Sheet2" to the right sheet name. Now how can I automatically apply this to all columns, so I do not need to keep changing the first value of `MATCH`? There's about 10k entries.

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. I'm using `=ISNA(MATCH(A:A,[old.xlsx]Sheet4!$A:$A,0))` now.

Comment: @andrewjackson The first part of the `MATCH` should be a single cell from the New sheet that you are looking up against the entire column of the Old sheet - so to test A1 , MATCH(A1,[old.xlsx]Sheet4!$A:$A,0)) , A2 MATCH(A2,[old.xlsx]Sheet4!$A:$A,0)) etc

Comment: Okay, finished. Thanks so much for your help, I've learn some very valuable skills today. =]